# Python RegEx in-text slash escape

Tags: python, regex

I apologize for the incoherent title, but it's hard to come up with one in this situation.

I have a bunch of texts and (almost) always they start either like this:

```
Word (Foo) - Main Text
```

or this:

```
Word (Foo/Bar) - Main Text
```

I want to remove everything before the `Main Text`, but it seems like the `/` character is messing up the regex I have.

So far I have this: `re.search('^[^)]*/*\)(.*)$', my_text)`

I've tested it on the regex101 site, and it should work on both instances (either with or without the `/`) However, when I plug it in my Python code, it returns a `NoneType` when it encounters a `/`. What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you matching `/*`? Isn't it already accounted for by `[^)]*`?

Comment: Well, your pattern finds a match - https://ideone.com/B6OlMa

Comment: Why not match against the first ` - `?

Answer (score 2):

Do:

```
^[^-]*-\s*(.*)
```

Now only captured group is your desired portion.

- `^[^-]*` matches substring upto first `-`
- `-` matches a literal `-`, `\s*` matches zero or more whitespace
- The only captured group `(.*)` matches rest of the string

**Example:**

```
In [10]: s = 'Word (Foo/Bar) - Main Text'

In [11]: re.search(r'^[^-]*-\s*(.*)', s).group(1)
Out[11]: 'Main Text'
```

Comment: This works great, but it doesn't capture any text after newline `\n`. Is there a way to capture the newline as well?

Comment: @Zlo yes, use `re.M` (`re.MULTILINE`): `re.search(r'^[^-]*-\s*(.*)', s, re.M).group(1)`